# C# Dataset saves over first record

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, dataset

I made a program with a dataset and a save button that should save each record into the dataset.  When you hit save for record 1, it saves correctly but when you hit save for record 2 it saves record 2 correctly, but also saves over record 1.  When you save record 3 it saves record 3 correctly, but saves over record 1 again.

For example-
If you save 1 record-
1.Record 1's data

If you save 2 records-
1.Record 2's data
2.Record 2's data

If you save 3 records you end up with this
1.Record 3's data
2.Record 2's data
3.Record 3's data

and so on.

Here is my code for the save

```
 DataTable t;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BSDataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table);
        t = BSDataSet.Tables["Table"];

    }

    private void saveEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InsertRecord();

    }

    private void InsertRecord()
    {

        DataRow newBSRow = t.NewRow();

        newBSRow ["Meal"] = mealComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        newBSRow ["Before meal BS"] = int.Parse(before_meal_BSTextBox.Text);
        newBSRow ["After meal BS"] = int.Parse(after_meal_BSTextBox.Text);
        newBSRow ["Carbs with meal"] = int.Parse(carbs_with_mealTextBox.Text);
        newBSRow ["Date"] = dateDateTimePicker.Value;           
        t.Rows.Add(newBSRow);
        newBSRow.AcceptChanges();
        mealComboBox.SelectedItem = "";
        before_meal_BSTextBox.Text = "";
        after_meal_BSTextBox.Text = "";
        carbs_with_mealTextBox.Text = "";

    }
```

Comment: How do you save the table?

Comment: Whoops, I was editing my code to make it more compact for this post and accidentally deleted what I use to save.  I use newBSRow.AcceptChanges();